# How to fixed the width & height of Scroll bar of Messenger in Html/Css/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css, messenger

I am designing the Messenger in Html/Css/JavaScript in which their is two sides one includes contacts and the other one includes the messages. I add scroll bar in both sides, but the height is not fit on screen, it is showing error and it is not responsive.

**How to fixed the scroll bar on screen like it is movable with screen and it will be responsive?**

**HTML**

```
<div class="container bootstrap snippet">
    <div class="tile tile-alt" id="messages-main">
        <div class="ms-menu">
            <div class="ms-user clearfix">
                <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar1.png" alt="" class="img-avatar pull-left">
                <div>Signed in as <br> m-hollaway@gmail.com</div>
            </div>

            <div class="p-15">
                <div class="dropdown">

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="list-group lg-alt" id="scroll">
                <a class="list-group-item media" href="">
                    <div class="pull-left">
                        <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar2.png" alt="" class="img-avatar">
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <div class="list-group-item-heading">Davil Parnell</div>
                    </div>
                </a>

                <a class="list-group-item media" href="">
                    <div class="pull-left">
                        <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar3.png" alt="" class="img-avatar">
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <div class="list-group-item-heading">Ann Watkinson</div>
                    </div>
                </a>

                <a class="list-group-item media" href="">
                    <div class="pull-left">
                        <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar4.png" alt="" class="img-avatar">
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <div class="list-group-item-heading">Marse Walter</div>
                    </div>
                </a>

                <a class="list-group-item media" href="">
                    <div class="lv-avatar pull-left">
                        <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar5.png" alt="" class="img-avatar">
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <div class="list-group-item-heading">Jeremy Robbins</div>
                    </div>
                </a>

                <a class="list-group-item media" href="">
                    <div class="lv-avatar pull-left">
                        <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar6.png" alt="" class="img-avatar">
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <div class="list-group-item-heading">Reginald Horace</div>
                    </div>
                </a>

                <a class="list-group-item media" href="">
                    <div class="pull-left">
                        <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar7.png" alt="" class="img-avatar">
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <div class="list-group-item-heading">Shark Henry</div>
                    </div>
                </a>

                <a class="list-group-item media" href="">
                    <div class="pull-left">
                        <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar1.png" alt="" class="img-avatar">
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <div class="list-group-item-heading">Paul Van Dack</div>
                    </div>
                </a>

                <a class="list-group-item media" href="">
                    <div class="lv-avatar pull-left">
                        <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar2.png" alt="" class="img-avatar">
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <div class="list-group-item-heading">James Anderson</div>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a class="list-group-item media" href="">
                    <div class="lv-avatar pull-left">
                        <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar2.png" alt="" class="img-avatar">
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <div class="list-group-item-heading">James Anderson</div>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a class="list-group-item media" href="">
                    <div class="lv-avatar pull-left">
                        <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar2.png" alt="" class="img-avatar">
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <div class="list-group-item-heading">James Anderson</div>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a class="list-group-item media" href="">
                    <div class="lv-avatar pull-left">
                        <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar2.png" alt="" class="img-avatar">
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <div class="list-group-item-heading">James Anderson</div>
                    </div>
                </a>

                <a class="list-group-item media" href="">
                    <div class="lv-avatar pull-left">
                        <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar3.png" alt="" class="img-avatar">
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <div class="list-group-item-heading">Kane Williams</div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>


        </div>

        <div class="ms-body">
            <div class="action-header clearfix">
                <div class="visible-xs" id="ms-menu-trigger">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </div>

                <div class="pull-left hidden-xs">
                    <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar2.png" alt="" class="img-avatar m-r-10">
                    <div class="lv-avatar pull-left">

                    </div>
                    <span>David Parbell</span>
                </div>

                <ul class="ah-actions actions">

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
                            <i class="fa fa-sort"></i>
                        </a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Latest</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Oldest</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>                             
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
                            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                        </a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Delete</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Block Messages</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Report as Spam</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

    <div id="scroll">

            <div class="message-feed media">
                <div class="pull-left">
                    <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar1.png" alt="" class="img-avatar">
                </div>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <div class="mf-content">
                        Quisque consequat arcu eget odio cursus, ut tempor arcu vestibulum. Etiam ex arcu, porta a urna non, lacinia pellentesque orci. Proin semper sagittis erat, eget condimentum sapien viverra et. Mauris volutpat magna nibh, et condimentum est rutrum a. Nunc sed turpis mi. In eu massa a sem pulvinar lobortis.
                    </div>
                    <small class="mf-date"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 20/02/2015 at 09:00</small>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="message-feed right">
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar2.png" alt="" class="img-avatar">
                </div>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <div class="mf-content">
                        Mauris volutpat magna nibh, et condimentum est rutrum a. Nunc sed turpis mi. In eu massa a sem pulvinar lobortis.
                    </div>
                    <small class="mf-date"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 20/02/2015 at 09:30</small>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="message-feed media">
                <div class="pull-left">
                    <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar1.png" alt="" class="img-avatar">
                </div>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <div class="mf-content">
                        Etiam ex arcumentum
                    </div>
                    <small class="mf-date"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 20/02/2015 at 09:33</small>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="message-feed right">
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar2.png" alt="" class="img-avatar">
                </div>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <div class="mf-content">
                        Etiam nec facilisis lacus. Nulla imperdiet augue ullamcorper dui ullamcorper, eu laoreet sem consectetur. Aenean et ligula risus. Praesent sed posuere sem. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
                    </div>
                    <small class="mf-date"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 20/02/2015 at 10:10</small>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="message-feed media">
                <div class="pull-left">
                    <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar1.png" alt="" class="img-avatar">
                </div>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <div class="mf-content">
                        Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam ac tortor ut elit sodales varius. Mauris id ipsum id mauris malesuada tincidunt. Vestibulum elit massa, pulvinar at sapien sed, luctus vestibulum eros. Etiam finibus tristique ante, vitae rhoncus sapien volutpat eget
                    </div>
                    <small class="mf-date"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 20/02/2015 at 10:24</small>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="msb-reply clearfix">
                <textarea placeholder="What's on your mind...">
                </textarea>
                <button><i class="fa fa-file"></i></button>
                 <button><i class="fa fa-camera"></i></button>
                <button><i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i></button>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    font-family: Roboto,sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #767676;
    background-color: #edecec;
    width:100%;
}

.container{
    width:100%;
}

div#scroll {
    height: 500px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#messages-main {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
#messages-main:after, #messages-main:before {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
#messages-main .ms-menu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #eee;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 240px;
    background: #fff;
}
@media (min-width:768px) {
    #messages-main .ms-body {
    padding-left: 240px;
}
}@media (max-width:767px) {
    #messages-main .ms-menu {
    height: calc(100% - 58px);
    display: none;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 58px;
}
#messages-main .ms-menu.toggled {
    display: block;
}
#messages-main .ms-body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
}
#messages-main .ms-user {
    padding: 15px;
    background: #f8f8f8;
}
#messages-main .ms-user>div {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px 5px 0 15px;
    font-size: 11px;
}
#messages-main #ms-compose {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 120px;
    z-index: 1;
    right: 30px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .28);
}
#ms-menu-trigger {
    user-select: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 19px;
}
#ms-menu-trigger i {
    font-size: 21px;
}
#ms-menu-trigger.toggled i:before {
    content: '\f2ea'
}
.fc-toolbar:before, .login-content:after {
    content: ""
}
.message-feed {
    padding: 20px;
}
#footer, .fc-toolbar .ui-button, .fileinput .thumbnail, .four-zero, .four-zero footer>a, .ie-warning, .login-content, .login-navigation, .pt-inner, .pt-inner .pti-footer>a {
    text-align: center;
}
.message-feed.right>.pull-right {
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.message-feed:not(.right) .mf-content {
    background: #03a9f4;
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
.message-feed.right .mf-content {
    background: #eee;
}
.mf-content {
    padding: 12px 17px 13px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 80%
}
.mf-date {
    display: block;
    color: #B3B3B3;
    margin-top: 7px;
}
.mf-date>i {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}
.msb-reply {
    box-shadow: 0 -20px 20px -5px #fff;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 30px;
    border-top: 1px solid #eee;
    background: #f8f8f8;
}
.four-zero, .lc-block {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 11px rgba(0, 0, 0, .27);
}
.msb-reply textarea {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 13px;
    border: 0;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    resize: none;
    height: 60px;
    background: 0 0;
}
.msb-reply button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 60px;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #2196f3;
    background: 0 0;
}
.msb-reply button:hover {
    background: #f2f2f2;
}
.img-avatar {
    height: 37px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 37px;
}
.list-group.lg-alt .list-group-item {
    border: 0;
}
.p-15 {
    padding: 15px!important;
}
.btn:not(.btn-alt) {
    border: 0;
}
.action-header {
    position: relative;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    padding: 15px 13px 15px 17px;
}
.ah-actions {
    z-index: 3;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 7px;
    position: relative;
}
.actions {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.actions>li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.actions:not(.a-alt)>li>a>i {
    color: #939393;
}
.actions>li>a>i {
    font-size: 20px;
}
.actions>li>a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.ms-body{
    background:#fff;    
}
#ms-menu-trigger {
    user-select: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 19px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#ms-menu-trigger, .message-feed.right {
    text-align: right;
}
#ms-menu-trigger, .toggle-switch {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
}
```

**JSFIDDLE:-**
https://jsfiddle.net/ggshn2da/

Comment: yeah, check on the Jsfiddle:- https://jsfiddle.net/ggshn2da/

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw ?????

Comment: Ok, but this is not complete solution, it is just the answer of second question...

Comment: And now i disaccepted??

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the first question but for the second one you only have to move that div outside.

```
<div class="msb-reply clearfix">
    <textarea placeholder="What's on your mind..."></textarea>
    <button><i class="fa fa-file"></i></button>
    <button><i class="fa fa-camera"></i></button>
    <button><i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i></button>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ggshn2da/1/

Comment: Thanks for that one and please can you separate the file and camera icons from paper-plane icon, Please....

Comment: And the first question is that the height of both sides are not same and it is not fit on screen, Like Facebook Messenger..